# Presenting a UIViewController when on landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uideviceorientation

What is the best way to show a UIViewController only when the device is on landscape mode?
The modal view controller should present itself modally when the device is on landscape mode and should dismiss itself when going back to portrait.

Since `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation :(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` is only called once (and not for every `UIViewController`), how should the navigation controller be set up?

Comment: Are you saying you want a second vc to be added modally only when in a certain orientation, or do you want one vc to change dimensions?

Comment: @JamesPaolantonio I want the the view controller to be added modally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're looking for is

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)o duration:(NSTimeInterval)t;
```

Comment: That's what I'm using but when trying to dismiss the view controller in that method and going back to the initial view controller (which is a `UITableViewController`), the orientation is  landscape. Is there a way to force portrait orientation?

Comment: maybe wait until the rotation finishes? didRotateFromyinterfaceOrientation method...